# How to store user inputs in a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I keep trying this and it still says it is wrong. It keeps saying that numberOfRounds is undefined. Is there another way I can do it? I want it to run the statement "Choose the ___ color" the amount of times the user wants.

```html
<html>
<!--This is the start screen that you see to begin the game. You also select how many rounds of the game you would like.-->
<font size="6"><center><strong><p id="startScreen">Welcome to the Random Color Game.</p></strong></center></font>
<font size="4"><center><p id="startScreen2">How many many rounds of the game would you like?</p>
<form id="numberOfRounds"><p id="startScreen3">I would like <input id="numberOfRounds" type="number" min="1" max="20" name="numberOfRounds"> rounds.</p>
<p id="startScreen5">To start playing the game, push begin.</p></center></font>

<center><h4 id="sayColor"></h4></center>


<center><p id="startButton"><button type="button" onclick="startGame();buttonColors();">Begin</button></p></center>
<!--this is the paragraph that will have all the buttons placed inside.-->
<center><p id="game"></p><center>

<script>
 
 var randomNumber = 0;
 var redPressed = false;
 var bluePressed = false;
 var greenPressed = false;
 var purplePressed = false;
 var orangePressed = false;
 var x = 1;

function startGame()
{
 buttonColors();
 //gets rid of the start screen text
 document.getElementById("startScreen").innerHTML = "";
 document.getElementById("startScreen2").innerHTML = "";
 document.getElementById("startScreen3").innerHTML = "";
 document.getElementById("startScreen5").innerHTML = "";
 //makes the text for the game
 document.getElementById("startButton").innerHTML = "<button type='button' onclick='location.reload()'>Restart</button>";
 document.getElementById("game").innerHTML = "<button type='button' onclick='redPressed = true;redCheck();' style='background-color:red'>Red</button><button type='button' onclick='bluePressed = true;blueCheck();' style='background-color:blue'>Blue</button><button type='button' onclick='greenPressed = true;greenCheck();' style='background-color:green'>Green</button><button type='button' onclick='purplePressed = true;purpleCheck();' style='background-color:purple'>Purple</button><button type='button' onclick='orangePressed = true;orangeCheck();' style='background-color:orange'>Orange</button>";
 //checks to see if the function ran
 console.log("startGame() ran.");
 makeRounds();
}

function makeRounds()
{
 //takes the number of rounds and puts it into a variable so it shows the amount of questions you want
 var numberOfRounds = document.getElementById("numberOfRounds").value;
 console.log(numberOfRounds);
 x = numberOfRounds*2;
 console.log(x);
 while (x<=numberOfRounds)
 {
  randomNumber = ( Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));
  console.log(randomNumber);
 }
}

function buttonColors()
{
 if (randomNumber==1)
 {
  document.getElementById("sayColor").innerHTML = "Push the red button."
 }
 if (randomNumber==2)
 {
  document.getElementById("sayColor").innerHTML = "Push the blue button."
 }
 if (randomNumber==3)
 {
  document.getElementById("sayColor").innerHTML = "Push the green button."
 }
 if (randomNumber==4)
 {
  document.getElementById("sayColor").innerHTML = "Push the purple button."
 }
 if (randomNumber==5)
 {
  document.getElementById("sayColor").innerHTML = "Push the orange button."
 }
}

function redCheck()
{
 if (randomNumber==1)
 {
  correct();
 }
 else
 {
  incorrect();
 }
 x--;
}

function blueCheck()
{
 if (randomNumber==2)
 {
  correct();
 }
 else
 {
  incorrect();
 }
 x--;
}

function greenCheck()
{
 if (randomNumber==3)
 {
  correct();
 }
 else
 {
  incorrect();
 }
 x--;
}

function purpleCheck()
{
 if (randomNumber==4)
 {
  correct();
 }
 else
 {
  incorrect();
 }
 x--;
}

function orangeCheck()
{
 if (randomNumber==5)
 {
  correct();
 }
 else
 {
  incorrect();
 }
 x--;
}

function correct()
{
 console.log("DATS RIGHT!!");
 window.alert("Correct!")
}

function incorrect()
{
 console.log("Incorrect.");
 window.alert("Incorrect.");
}

</script>



</html>
```

Comment: You have multiple declarations of `numberOfRounds` id.

Comment: Your startGame() function clears the contents of startScreen3 which contains the numberOfRounds element. Capture this data before you delete the contents.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="numberOfRounds"><p id="startScreen3">I would like <input id="numberOfRounds" type="number" min="1" max="20" name="numberOfRounds"> rounds.</p>
```

Both have same id, numberOfRounds.